# Numbering bibliographies in the table of content within chapters but remove numbering for the last final bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I'm putting various chapters together (using `\include{}`) that each have a bibliography

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report} 

\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[round, sectionbib]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Yo the yo}

\citep{Grant1999}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{thesis}

\appendix 
\chapter{My appendix shall not be removed}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{thesis}
% \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}

\cleardoublepage

\chaptermark{{Bibliography}}
% \chapter{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{thesis}

\end{document}
```

Which gives this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

The final bibliography (edited to look like that):

[image]

```
@book{Grant1999,
    Address = {Princeton, New Jersey},
    Author = {Grant, Peter Raymond},
    Isbn = {0691084289 9780691084282},
    Publisher = {Princeton University Press},
    Rating = {5},
    Title = {{Ecology and evolution of Darwin's finches}},
    Year = {1999}
}
```

Comment: This looks like it will make duplicate complete bibliographies, as I don't see the chapterbib package or separate included files. Maybe you can elaborate on the intended result for more more chapters and more citations. With "chapterbib", bibliographies in the main document file are for the complete document while ones in `\include` files are for that file (typically a chapter). In natbib, the sectioning used by `\bibliography` is easy to change by redefining `\bibsection`... `\renewcommand\bibsection{\chapter*{\bibname}}` (and you could add `\markboth` if desired).

Comment: In my thesis file I do have the package ```\usepackage{chapterbib}```. I haven't put the ```include``` command as it is not working as a minimal example. I figured out that this was working within a chapter! ```\addtocounter{section}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}~~ Bibliography}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, "chapterbib" with the `[sectionbib]` option will use `\section*` for the partial bibliographies, but retain `\chapter*` for the whole-document bibliography.

Both the packages "tocbibind" and "natbib" change the bibliography sectioning to be more easily changed, by segregating the control in the command `\bibsection`, but they don't pay attention to the state of `\include` files that distinguish separate bibliographies. The easiest solution is to redefine `\bibsection` before the overall (final) bibliography

```
\renewcommand\bibsection{\chapter*{\bibname}}
```

This fits in well with the question where `\chaptermark` and `\addcontentsline` are used explicitly. It would also be good to move those bookkeeping commands into the revised `\bibsection`

```
\renewcommand\bibsection{\chapter*{\bibname}%
    \chaptermark{\bibname}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
}
```

but that doesn't save any typing.